# Recursion - Adding the subset of an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to decide if the sum of subset is a set num or not)...

I've read through most of the questions so far here on stackoverflow and have come up with nothing. I think the issue I'm finding is that I want to add together the elements in the combitorial subsets created. All together this should be done **recursively**. With the current code I have, I'm getting a stackoverflow error for recursion. (ironic)

So to clarify:

int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
the subset would be the size of say 2 and combinations would be

{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,4},{3,5},{4,5}
from this data I want to see if the subset say... equals 6, then the answers would be: {1,5} and {2,4} leaving me with true as a answer. In respect to the signature I would like to keep it the same because it corresponds with another method (outside of the issue because it only sends the array, n, and num to the method)

```
public static boolean subset(int[] array, int n, int num) {

    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int[] subarray = new int[n];
    int[] temp = new int[array.length - 1];
    int[] copy = array;

    subarray[count] = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        subarray[count] = array[i];
        count++;
        System.arraycopy(array, i, temp, 0, n);
    }
        for (int j = 0; j < subarray.length; j++) {
            sum += subarray[j];

            if (sum == num) 
                    return true;
        }
            subset(copy, n, goal);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why does a recursion recreate itself?

Comment: Take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670732/how-to-find-if-any-values-in-array-add-up-to-n/21672921#21672921

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a plausible idea for one?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // New sublist to store values from 0 to i
        int[] list = new int[array.length - 1];

        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            list[j] = array[j+1];
        }

        // Here you call this recursively with your Parent list from i+1
        // index and working list from 0 to i
        subsetSum(list, n, goal);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    if (sum == goal) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: @PopoFibo Admittedly, I did use your code! But I can't figure out how to change it to fit my scenario. I've been coding for the past hour unknowingly how to adapt it!

Comment: Didn't realize you were the OP, yes the link was for your benefit itself - retracting my earlier comment

Comment: @PopoFibo Could you help give a suggestion as to how to make this work? There is an error and can't seem to figure it out (still - after all these hours - how silly)